# Where do I ask odd systemd questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have not found exact duplicates for

> How do symlinks work in systemd unit files (and when/why wont they)?
>
> Specifically: How to inherit settings from a systemd unit to a newly created template?

but do believe that [it is sufficiently complicated](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/902) to warrant 1-2 quite detailed Q&A on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bsystemd%5D%20symlink), [unix&linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsystemd%5D%20symlink) or [here on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bsystemd%5D%20symlink).

My specific use case is likely only relevant to *managing IT in a business env* and the unexpected behavior may be changed in systemd anyway, but a good generic answer will likely help many others on any of those sites for as long as older current versions are in use.

1. Where do I post my question (I intend to provide atleast a partial answer)?
2. May I stuff my question with the other on-topic use cases to make the question more generally useful to potentially related problems like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/948506/systemctl-shows-service-file-not-found-even-though-service-file-is-present)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We like interesting IT questions.

You can certainly ask complex or unusual questions about how various aspects of systemd work. But to be sure you get a good answer, you should include as much detail about your use case as your company will allow you to do. Avoid making the question too generic; this usually doesn't work and makes it harder to provide a good answer.

Comment: Once again, this turned out to be the more helpful approach. By dividing my problem into smaller pieces, i eventually figured out i was entirely wrong about which part was actually broken.